# Xamarin.Forms Cross-Platform templates missing on Visual Studio 2015 Professional

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I have fresh install of Visual Studio 2015 Professional and after click on **File - New Project - Templates - Visual C# - Cross Platform** I don't get any usual templates like Blank app or Cross Platform App (Xamarin.Forms or Native). I had installed all available items during Visual Studio installation and would like to target iPhone, Android and WF platform in a same project.

*How to install missing templates?*

[image: Missing templates should be here available]

[image: All features were selected during initial install]

All features including Xamarin were selected during initial install of Visual Studio.

Comment: Follow the official guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/windows/#vs2015

Comment: Yes, I've done it. Xamarin is successfuly installed and I can run existing Xamarin.Forms apps on all available platforms. This templates are the only thing missing.

Comment: Rerun the [Visual Studio installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771552.aspx): "select the Custom option in the installer, and check the box under Cross Platform Mobile Development > C#/.NET (Xamarin)"

Comment: The box is already checked, as it was during initial installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by performing a **thorough Xamarin uninstall**, then I installed it again through Visual Studio installer. Details and the exact 12 steps which helped me are described here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/visual-studio/troubleshooting/uninstall-xamarinvs/

After this I got all templates needed (iPhone, Android & Windows Phone). However, after recent update of Xamarin tools I noticed that Windows Phone project isn't added to the solution any more but replaced with Universal Windows Platform.

Comment: why not using visual studio installer?

Comment: Cant't we download only templates from some where  ?